# Join strings in each group and assign back to the original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with two columns: `user` and `lang`. Each user knows one or more languages:

```
     lang     user
0  Python     Mike
1   Scala     Mike
2       R     John
3   Julia  Michael
4    Java  Michael
```

I need to get for each row in `user` all the languages which he/she knows. I can do that:

```
df.groupby('user')['lang'].apply(lambda x:', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

But I get this:

```
      user           lang
0     John              R
1  Michael    Julia, Java
2     Mike  Python, Scala
```

Instead of what I want:

```
           lang     user
0  Python,Scala     Mike
1  Python,Scala     Mike
2             R     John
3    Julia,Java  Michael
4    Julia,Java  Michael
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"lang":["Python","Scala","R","Julia","Java"],
                   "user":["Mike","Mike","John","Michael","Michael"]})
print(df)
```

Comment: Sorry, I know how this is going to come across, but...why do you want the users to be duplicated in the dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transform` to "broadcast" the `groupby` result to each row in the input.

```
df['lang'] = df.groupby('user')['lang'].transform(', '.join)
df
            lang     user
0  Python, Scala     Mike
1  Python, Scala     Mike
2              R     John
3    Julia, Java  Michael
4    Julia, Java  Michael
```